# Bootstrap 3 right align a select input group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to figure out how to right align select input groups in bootstrap 3.  No matter what i try it aligns on the right.  If you look at the fiddle below, im trying to align the select and button inputs to the right of the gray box.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPE4h/)

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="header-right-container" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color: #eee;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></span>
                            <select class="form-control input-sm" style="width:150px">
                                <option value="1">option 1</option>
                                <option value="2">option 2</option>
                                <option value="3">option 3</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a id="headerUserButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="##">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> User Name
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <!-- dropdown menu links -->
                                <li><a href="#">Option A</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Option B</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Option C</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--- /.btn-group --->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: Just one comment is that according to the bootstrap [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) it is "invalid" to have anything other than `col` as child of `row`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `pull-right` to your `input-group` and `btn-group`. Then move `style="width:150px"` from  `form-control` to `input-group`.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/TPE4h/7/).

Answer (score 1):

Add Width to input-group and put a pull-right to it. The select would be alligned to right.

http://jsfiddle.net/MGD2y/

**HTML:**

```
<body>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="header-right-container" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color: #eee;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
                                <div class="input-group pull-right" style="width: 200px;">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></span>
                                    <select class="form-control input-sm" style="width:150px">
                                        <option value="1">option 1</option>
                                        <option value="2">option 2</option>
                                        <option value="3">option 3</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a id="headerUserButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="##">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> User Name
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <!-- dropdown menu links -->
                                        <li><a href="#">Option A</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Option B</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Option C</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div><!--- /.btn-group --->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
```

Comment: your fiddle does not align correctly. the style must be removed from the select tag as well as added to the `input-group` div. also the `col-md-4` that you added must be removed.

Comment: actually, the `col-md-4` doesn't need to be removed, but to properly align with the button below, surround the `btn-group` with the same column. [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/MGD2y/1/)

Comment: Main moto was to make it right aligned. It was not formatting the code.

Comment: true, but it may not be obvious that a bootstrap column adds padding, which would cause it to be misaligned with other elements not in a column.